# Jquery/Regex not applying to val / var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I'm doing something wrong, that's for sure :-) I checked https://regex101.com/ to check if the Regex is correct and couldn't find any problems. Also I'm pretty new to jQuery/JavaScript but the console isn't firing any Syntax errors etc.

I tested the code to replace 'Goedemorgen' to 'Goodmorning'. **that worked fine** so I guess the fault is within the replace/regex? I'm not sure! Any help would be appreciated.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".wpcf7-number").focusout(function() {

        var InputVal = $('.wpcf7-number').val();
        var InputValNew = InputVal.replace(/^[0-9]*$/g,'');

        console.log(InputValNew + ' New Var');

    });

});
```

The output I wish to get:
033-2245-22455 to: 033224522455 (so without the -).

**Don't be harsh I'm still learning!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to remove all characters that are not digits.

You need to move `^` into the character class (at the beginning) so that it negates the meaning of the range, and remove quantifier and anchors.

```
var InputValNew = InputVal.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
```

Here is the [regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/yM0sA7/1)

You regex - `/^[0-9]*$/g` - matches a whole string that is either empty or only contains digits. `^` here is a start of string anchor, and `$` is the end of string acnhor. `*` means *0 or more occurrences. So, `/g` global modifier is meaningless: you cannot have multiple matches if you pass 1 string and want to match it fully.

There is also `\D` class matching *any non-digit character*. It is an absolute synonym of `[^\d]` or `[^0-9]` in JS.

Comment: I hope my answer clears out some regex intricacies for you. Please drop a comment if there is something you still have doubt of.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\D` to match any none digit value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".wpcf7-number").focusout(function() {
    var InputVal = $('.wpcf7-number').val();
    var InputValNew = InputVal.replace(/\D/g, '');
    console.log(InputValNew + ' New Var');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text class="wpcf7-number" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a hard pick to choice either you or @stribizhev answer but he did explain what was going wrong. Still I want to thanks you for your time!

Comment: I think his answer is better than mine, he well explained what wrong with your code..  anyway glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Sample code which will work for you

```js
var a ="033-2245-22455";
var b =a.replace(/-/g ,'');
alert(b);
```